# unique reference id generation in React

Tags: reactjs

To,Generate invoice number like : PISC/2021/01/00005 like this on reactjs? HERE ,User can define first invoiceterm as their own.hI Have Problem creating this type of invoices where last invoice term increases by 1?

**code**

```
var d = new Date(); 
var formattedDate = moment(d).format('YYYY/MM/DD').slice(0,6);
const lastinvterm=Id.toString().padStart(5, "0")  
const inv="PISC"+formattedDate+lastinvterm
```

Comment: If you're using a database, how about letting an auto increment column handle this for you?

Comment: "I Have Problem creating this type of invoices where last invoice term increases by 1?" Where are you trying to increment the lastinvterm by 1?